# Handle elements after innerHTML or html(). Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding new element through `html()` function of jQuery. Then I want to handel it. Is it possible to do that in way you see here?

```
 $("#renamePlaylist").click(function(){
     var aa = '<input type="text" name="plst_name"  value="'+$("#playlist_header").find("span").text()+'" size="'+Math.round($("#playlist_header").find("span").text().length/2)+'">'+
              '<input id="renameCurrent" type="image" name="+" value="submit" alt="+">'; 
     $("#playlist_header").find('span').html(aa);                 
 });

 $("#renameCurrent").click(function(){
     alert('hello')
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$("#renameCurrent").live('click', function(){
   alert('hello')
});
```

Or, run the bind after you create it, like this:

```
$("#renamePlaylist").click(function(){
  var aa = '<input type="text" name="plst_name"  value="'+$("#playlist_header").find("span").text()+'" size="'+Math.round($("#playlist_header").find("span").text().length/2)+'">'+
           '<input id="renameCurrent" type="image" name="+" value="submit" alt="+">'; 
  $("#playlist_header").find('span').html(aa);
  $("#renameCurrent").click(function(){ alert('hello'); });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.delegate()` to handle elements that are dynamically added to the `#playlist_header` container.

```
$("#playlist_header").delegate('#renameCurrent', 'click', function(){
     alert('hello');
 });
```

Or just add the `.click()` handler when you create the element.

```
 $("#renamePlaylist").click(function(){
     var $aa = $('<input type="text" name="plst_name"  value="'+$("#playlist_header").find("span").text()+'" size="'+Math.round($("#playlist_header").find("span").text().length/2)+'">'+
          '<input id="renameCurrent" type="image" name="+" value="submit" alt="+">'); 
     $aa.filter('#renameCurrent').click(function() {
          alert('hello');
     });
     $("#playlist_header span").html($aa);  // Edit from @Nick's comment.          
 });
```

Comment: The second version would add a click to an extra element :) Also just as a tip, `.html($aa)` is a shortcut ;)

Comment: @Nick - Indeed it would. Fixed. :o) Although, I thought `.html($aa)` would result in `[object Object]`. EDIT: Nope, I was wrong.